# Finding percentage of not-null values in each column for every subset in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, notnull

I'm trying to print the percentage of not-null values in every column for every subset of groupby. The groupby is performed on the column 'Agent'. Can you please help me with this? I tried something like this:

[code]

```
df.groupby('Agent').apply(lambda x: x.notnull().sum()/len(x)*100)
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to get the percentage of non-null values is probably to convert the data columns to True or False and then just do a groupby mean operation. The mean operation on a binary column is implicitly calculating the percentage of values that are True since it treats True as 1 and False as 0.

```py
agents = ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C', 'D']
data = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Agent': agents,
    'x': range(len(agents)),
    'y': range(len(agents))
})

data.loc[[0, 4, 5], 'x'] = np.nan
data.loc[[1, 3, 9], 'y'] = np.nan

# Percentage non-missing grouped by Agent
100*(1-data.set_index('Agent').isnull().groupby(level='Agent').mean())
```